# Dynamic stored procedure based upon json input

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to write a dynamic stored procedure based upon if the structure of input JSON object.

```
{
  "store": {
    "storeId": 123,
    "name": "TEST",
    "location":{                     //This is optional
      "address1": "Some Address",
      "address2": "Some Address"
     }
  }
}
```

In database I have two tables **STORE** and **LOCATION**.
While writing a stored procedure I want to validate if the location key is present or not, something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT JSON_VALUE(@store, '$.store.location'))
BEGIN
Select * from LOCATION where STORE_ID = JSON_VALUE(@store, '$.store.storeId')
END
```

But this IF-condition always returns true. Even if the 'location' key is not present. How can this be implemented?

Comment: *"if the location is key is present or not"* huh? What does *is key is present* mean?

Comment: As for why the `EXISTS` always returns `TRUE`, that's because `EXISTS` checks if any rows are returned, not if the value returned is `NULL` or not. A scalar function will *always* return a value, as `NULL` is stilla  value; just an unknown one. You want `IF JSON_VALUE(@store, '$.store.location') IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF EXISTS` returns `TRUE` when at lease one row is returned by the subquery. When you run the query and the optional value is not present, a single row, single column result is returned with a `NULL` value. Consequently, the IF condition will always be `TRUE` regardless.

Below is one way to execute the query only when the `location` json object is present (edited to use `JSON_QUERY` per the comment by @Zhorov):

```
IF (SELECT JSON_QUERY(@store, '$.store.location')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    Select * from LOCATION where STORE_ID = JSON_VALUE(@store, '$.store.storeId')
END
```

Comment: `JSON_VALUE(@store, '$.store.location'))` will return `null` or an error (in `strict` mode), because `$.store.location` points to a JSON object, not to a scalar value. I think that `JSON_QUERY()` is more appropriate here. But I agree, that the essential part of the answer is the use of the `EXISTS` keyword. +1 from my side.

Comment: First `SELECT` is unnecessary. I wish there was a `JSON_EXIST` function (I also wish we had JQuery, but whatever...)